# Relative import python (no known parent)

Tags: python, import

I have the following dir structure:

[image]

both the train and utils dir have **init**.py. I am trying to import utils.logger from within train/main.py:

```
from ..utils.logger import Logger
```

but it gives the "not known parent package error":

> File "train/main.py", line 4, in 
> from ..utils.logger import Logger ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: I think you'll need to have a file outside `ml_logic` that'll have something like `from ml_logic import run; run()`.

Comment: but I cannot change the structure. Structure needs to remain as it is.

Comment: I hope someone can give a better answer, but I think it's a problem with relative imports. Generally I'll use absolute imports if I need to run from _inside_ a module, and relative imports if the module is meant to be imported by something else.